# C# ListViewItemCollection does not contain a definition for Count

Tags: c#, listview, count

In C#, I have a ListView control and want to obtain a count of items currently in the control's item collection, but the code below produces the error:

'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvitems = lvDropSummary.Items;
int iLVItemsCount = lvitems.Count();
```

I haven't seen specific code examples anywhere getting the count of all items in a listview, but according to the documentation (and intellisense), the property exists:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.count(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq` in your using statement /header section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are trying to use like a method

`int iLVItemsCount = lvitems.Count();`

change it to the following should work

```
 int iLVItemsCount = lvitems.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what DJ KRAZE said. Just wanted to add, (not sure if you did it on purpose) but unless you are modifying the items collection before you do the count, you can simplify to:

```
int iLVItemsCount = lvDropSummary.Items.Count;
```